# Object-Oriented Languages on Bare Metal

Tags: oop, bare-metal

I'm aware of C++ and Object Pascal, but are there any other object-oriented languages whose compilers currently can compile them to run on a machine with no operating system?  If there are, do they have a sizeable community and acceptably good documentation?

Comment: I guess you're really asking "are there any other OO languages that have *existing* compilers to raw machine code?", as pretty much all languages *could* be compiled thus...

Comment: Yes, if you want to be persnickety.  :-)  I'll update the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Ada](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ada_%28programming_language%29) is often used in embedded environments.  I don't know how much of a community it has nowadays, but it's got a tradition of excellent documentation, and (in my humble opinion) its designers made different mistakes from the mistakes of the C family, which is refreshing.

Comment: A relative big Community can be found in the #Ada IRC channel on freenode.net

Answer (score 1):

Most of devkits use GCC. So you can choose any language which GCC supports. Of course, there are difficulties, e.g. calling/linking library functions written in C, or lack of standard (non-C/C++) language libraries...

Answer (score 1):

[Tcl](http://www.tcl.tk/about/language.html) is used in embedded applications.  There are OO extensions to it, and I believe there are plans to bake in some of that functionality natively.